# Dynamically add AngularJS Script

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've got a project that's has a very rapid development cycle which causes many changes in the main `app.js` file. This file has the configs as well as controllers for the AngularJS app that's being used as part of the project. This created Caching issues which I tried solving as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = document.createElement('script')
    s.setAttribute('src', 'assets/js/app-v2.js?v='+(new Date().getMilliseconds())); 
    document.body.appendChild(s);
</script>
```

However, this gives me an error in angular saying:

```
Failed to instantiate module appName due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'appName' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

My HTML is setup as

```
<html ng-app="appName">....</html>
```

So I tried setting the `ng-app` dynamically after loading the script but that doesn't work either. Gives me the same issue as earlier. Is it possible for me to add the appName dynamically during or after the load of the `app-v2.js` file?

Comment: What is the nature of the "caching issues"? The file is updated but when you refresh you still get the old version? If so, I don't understand how setting `ng-app` dynamically helps

Comment: @NewDev, For some reason, even though the file is updated on the server, I get a 304 Not Modified flag on calling it.

Comment: Ok, but how are you planning to resolve that with dynamic `ng-app`?

Comment: @NewDev, I was assuming the error I was getting is due to `ng-app` being set before the `js` file is called. If that's not the case, how do I solve the error that I get plus keep this version controlled method of adding the js file?

Comment: Have a look in this http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/08/dynamically-injecting-script-tags-with-angularjs.aspx

Comment: Take a look at ocLazyLoad library  https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad, which registers modules (or controllers, services etc on existing module) at run time and also loads them using requireJs or other such library.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this answer from the stackoverflow while I was facing same issue.

bootstrap() will call the AngularJS compiler for you, just like ng-app.

```
// Make module Foo and store $controllerProvider in a global
 var controllerProvider = null;
 angular.module('Foo', [], function($controllerProvider) {
 controllerProvider = $controllerProvider;
});
// Bootstrap Foo
angular.bootstrap($('body'), ['Foo']);

 // .. time passes ..

 // Load javascript file with Ctrl controller
 angular.module('Foo').controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
 $scope.msg = "It works! rootScope is " + $rootScope.$id +
    ", should be " + $('body').scope().$id;
 });
 // Load html file with content that uses Ctrl controller
 $('<div id="ctrl" ng-controller="Ctrl" ng-bind="msg">').appendTo('body');

 // Register Ctrl controller manually
 // If you can reference the controller function directly, just run:
 // $controllerProvider.register(controllerName, controllerFunction);
 // Note: I haven't found a way to get $controllerProvider at this stage
 //    so I keep a reference from when I ran my module config
  function registerController(moduleName, controllerName) {
  // Here I cannot get the controller function directly so I
   // need to loop through the module's _invokeQueue to get it
   var queue = angular.module(moduleName)._invokeQueue;
for(var i=0;i<queue.length;i++) {
    var call = queue[i];
    if(call[0] == "$controllerProvider" &&
       call[1] == "register" &&
       call[2][0] == controllerName) {
        controllerProvider.register(controllerName, call[2][1]);
    }
}
}
 registerController("Foo", "Ctrl");
 // compile the new element
 $('body').injector().invoke(function($compile, $rootScope) {
 $compile($('#ctrl'))($rootScope);
 $rootScope.$apply();
});
```

Hope it will help you